# To get maximum row number in excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need one solution to the below scenario.

Lets say I have a table of data in four column. I want to know the maximum row in excel sheet. For eg: As you can see in the below table column B has maximum number of rows which is equal to 12.

```
    A   B   C   D
1   asd asd asd asd
2   asd asd asd asd
3   asd asd asd asd
4   asd asd asd asd
5   asd asd asd asd
6       asd     asd
7       asd     asd
8       asd
9       asd
10      asd
11      asd
12      asd
```

My solution is to individually check each column to get the maximum number of rows. Is there any other optimize solution to this??

Comment: @Chris: The question asked in the linked post is different than what i have asked. No doubt it has solution to my Answer but question is different. Question in that post is looking for last row in used range and I am not looking for Last used range.

Comment: and how is that different?

Comment: Count of rows return by used range and actual number of rows can be different. And that particular post asked for Last used cell or range. And I was asking for actual rows in sheet.

Comment: Look at the accepted answer by Sid, in particular the method using `Find`

Comment: Yes, Answer applies to me too. And Yes, my question was intended to find the actual rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use CountIf(range, "<>"&"").

More options:
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/07/02/excel-countif-examples/

After that use Max(range) to get the maximum number.

Comment: How can we use countif? Data is not same in any column. What I have used is sample text. Your formula will get me all non blank cells for each column right??